# Comparing values in two different dictionaries

Tags: algorithm, subsequence

Given two dictionaries

> a={'aabb': ['aabb'], 'abcd': ['abcd', 'abce', 'abcf'], 'abbc': ['abbc']}

> b={'aabb': 1, 'abcd': 2, 'abbc': 1}

Get the all values from a where thr key has a max value in b
in example :
In b 'abcd' has a max value so we `print(['abcd', 'abce', 'abcf'])`

Can some one help me with the solution ?

Comment: Show us what did you code by now? Where is your attempt to solve this task?

Comment: Where exactly did you get stuck? Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the python code for the question, Please let me know if there are any issues.

```py
    a = {'aabb': ['aabb'], 'abcd': ['abcd', 'abce', 'abcf'], 'abbc': ['abbc']}
    b = {'aabb': 1, 'abcd': 2, 'abbc': 1}
    final_list = []
    
    #fetch the values in dict a
    for key, value in a.items():
        for i in value:
            final_list.append(i)
    
    #fetch maximum value in dict b
    max_val = max(b.values()) 
    
    #fetch the key in dict b that has maximum value and is present in values of 
    #dict a
    for i in final_list:
        for key, value in b.items():
            if value == max_val:
                if key == i:
                    new_key = i
    print(a[new_key])
```